# Encontrar diferencias en dos columnas de dos dataframes con pandas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join

Tengo dos dataframes `F1` con 215 filas y `F2` con 195 filas, tienen en común una columna, `Localidad`, sin valores repetidos en los dos casos. Quiero encontrar las diferencias entre las dos columnas para identificar valores que pueden ser el mismo, pero escrito de forma diferente.

```
F1
Localidad
...
Alcabendas
Colmenar_Viejo
Las_Rozas
Los_Molinos
San_Martin 
Santa_Clara
...
------------------------------
F2
Localidad
...
Alcabendas
Colmenar_Viejo
Rozas,_Las
Molinos,_Los
S._Martin 
Sta._Clara
...
```

He probado con: `df=F1[['Localidad']].merge(F2[['Localidad']], how ='outer', indicator='right_only')`
pero muestra los valores que están en ambas o en una de las dos.

```
.....
108              Alcobendas        both
109           Comenar_Viejo        both
110               Las_Rozas   left_only
111             Los_Molinos   left_only
112              San_Martin   left_only
........
```

¿Hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo sin que aparezcan las que están en los dos dataframes? Agradeceré cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Puedes convertir esas columnas a conjuntos python, y usar aritmética de conjuntos. Por ejemplo `a=set(F1.Localidad); b=set(F2.Localidad)` para después calcular diferencias entre conjuntos, como `a-b` (te dará los que están en `a` pero no en `b`) o `b-a` (viceversa), o `(a|b) - (a&b)` (la unión menos la intersección), etc. según lo que necesites.

Answer (score 1):

Acá les muestro en ejemplo con estos sencillos frames, las columnas a comparar son:

- DF1 es **"lkey"**
- DF2 es **"rkey"**

Observen que en

- DF1 está la fila 3, está un valor D/5
- DF2 está la fila 3, está un valor E/9

Esos son van a ser los datos claves para ver las diferencias, puesto que en:

- DF1 no está el valor E/9
- DF2 no está el valor D/5

```
    >>> df1
      lkey  value
    0    A      1
    1    B      2
    2    C      3
    3    D      5


    >>> df2
      rkey  value
    0    A      6
    1    B      7
    2    C      8
    3    E      9
```

Usaría esta sencilla fórmula con el método "merge" de la biblioteca Pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lkey': ['B', 'D', 'A', 'C'],'value': [1, 2, 3, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'rkey': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'B'], 'value': [6, 7, 8, 9]})
merge = pd.merge(df1, df2 , how='outer', indicator='resultado',sort=True, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')
```

Ahora el resultado lo pueden obsevar en la columna "RESULTADO"

- both = el dato **está** en los DOS frames
- left_only = el datos **sólo está** en el DF1
- right_only = el dato **sólo está** en el DF2

Acá está el resultado

```
      lkey  value_x rkey  value_y   resultado
    0    A      3.0    A      6.0        both
    1    B      1.0    B      9.0        both
    2    C      5.0    C      7.0        both
    3    D      2.0  NaN      NaN   left_only
    4  NaN      NaN    E      8.0  right_only
```

Luego de manera sencilla se puede filtrar según las coincidencias de la columna "RESULTADO"

```py
    merge[merge.resultado=='left_only']
```

Dará como resultado los elementos que **SÓLO esán** en el DF1 y **NO están** en el DF2

```
    lkey    value_x rkey    value_y resultado
    3   D   2.0 NaN NaN left_only
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que el resultado que esperas, es el equivalente a un `antijoin` de SQL donde obtienes sólo aquellos registros que no cruzan en la join. [Aquí](https://riptutorial.com/es/sql/example/22934/terminologia-de-join--interno--exterior--semi--anti----) puedes consultar una explicación sencilla de estos  conceptos.
Partiendo de tu propio código, para obtener estos resultados en python, con un pequeño cambio podrías obtenerlo, así:

1. Cambia el valor de `indicator` y asigna `True`, tu línea quedaría así:

```
    outerjoin=df=F1[['Localidad']].merge(F2[['Localidad']], how ='outer', indicator=True)
    print(outerjoin)
```

Esto traerá todos los resultados de la `join` en la columna `_merge`, es decir, los `left_only`, `right_only` y `both`, con el siguiente resultado:

```
        Localidad      _merge
0      Alcabendas        both
1  Colmenar_Viejo        both
2       Las_Rozas   left_only
3     Los_Molinos   left_only
4      San_Martin   left_only
5     Santa_Clara   left_only
6      Rozas,_Las  right_only
7       S._Martin  right_only
8    Molinos,_Los  right_only
9      Sta._Clara  right_only
```

2. Teniendo este resultado, ahora hacemos el `antijoin`, es decir tomar aquellos registros que no están en ambos (donde `_merge` sea diferente de `both`), así:

```
    antijoin=outerjoin[~(outerjoin['_merge']=='both')].drop('_merge', axis=1)
    print(antijoin)
```

Y entonces tendrás en `antijoin` sólo aquellos valores que no están en ambos:

```
      Localidad
2     Las_Rozas
3   Los_Molinos
4    San_Martin
5   Santa_Clara
6    Rozas,_Las
7     S._Martin
8  Molinos,_Los
9    Sta._Clara
```